# How is the life on hit effect from Life Gems calculated?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

When you apply green gems (Life Gems) to weapons, you gain a percentage of life on hit. The actual description on the life gem item is "Weapon: Increase Health stolen by x%" (depending on the level of the gem). What does this percentage correspond to? Is it based on my total health? Or is it based on the weapon damage?

Comment: It sounds like it should be based on weapon attributes, but that's definitely not it, because I do heal with a regular sword without life on hit but with a life gem

Answer (score 2):

I have not played the game, but from doing some looking online I believe it is based on your weapons attributes, you may be assuming incorrectly the "Increase health stolen by x%".

Lets say that it's 20%. Instead of it being 20% *more* than your current life steal, I think it may just add on that 20%. So in your comment when you heal with a regular sword, that has 0% life on hit, you are still gaining health because the life gem increases your life on hit by 20%, meaning you now heal for 20% not 20% more than before.

You can test this out if you are able to see how much you are healing/how much damage you do. With the regular sword, the amount healed should be the % of the damage from the life gem.

Comment: My question is what does 20% mean. 20% of damage converted into health restored, or 20% of my health restored per hit, or something else entirely. 20% is ambiguous on its own.

Comment: @Unionhawk: If it were % of Talion's health bar, you'd be nigh unstoppable (because you'd get a notable health boost for every hit, and Talion attacks really rapidly in general). It's much more likely to be a % from the **damage dealt** by the weapon with the gem, which is also much more in line with the health gains that I've seen.

Comment: The actual percentage is more on the order of 7 for high tier gems

Comment: Since it says "health stolen" I am led to believe that it would be based on the % of damage. So if the gem is 7% and you deal 100 damage, you gain 7 life points.